published/target and host/container ports in docker
There are
docker run -p <host port>:<container port> <image name>

and
docker service create -p mode=host,published=8082,target=80 nginx

commands.
I understand that they serve different purposes but is host port and published the same thing (do they refer to the same concept?).
And similarly: container port / target port do they refer to the same concept?
To clarify my point: Let's assume that we create docker from scratch - would it be fair to call those parameters "host_port" and "container_port" in case of both commands?

I would say same concept yes, both map a host port to a container port. Even though running a container is something different then creating a new service in a Docker Swarm cluster.
